# Send Email to Multiple Account Contacts

Tags: trigger, workflow, configuration

I have a scenario where i need to send email to multiple contacts.

Under account contact we separate some contact with type - 'Approvers' and one account can have multiple contacts with type Approvers.
When a oppty status is changed to status 'Need Review' an email should be sent to all account contacts with type approvers.

Comment: You can do this via a Trigger or a workflow take a look at this https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000181218&language=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet may help to your scenario.

```
trigger sendEmail on Opportunity (before Update) {

    Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();

    if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isBefore) {
        for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new) {
            if(opp.AccountId <> null && opp.stageName != Trigger.OldMap.get(opp.Id).stageName && opp.stageName == 'Need Review') {
                accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
            }
        }
    } 

    if(accIds.size() > 0) {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for(Contact con : [Select Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accIds AND Email <> null AND Test_Type__c = 'Approvers']) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setToAddresses(new List<String> {con.Id});
            mail.setSubject('Test Subject');
            mail.setPlainTextBody('Test Mail');
            emailList.add(mail);
        }
        if(emailList.size() > 0) {
            Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);
        }
    }
}
```